# How to call a function that I'm passing in as an argument? It's throwing a type error 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

This is a test function and I'm passing in two other functions as the parameter (f), but when I try to do

```
bintest('isMemberR')
```

it gives me a type error.
Anyway just wondering how to convert the string to a function.

```
def bintest(f):      

    test1 = ((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 4)
    test2 = ((1, 2, 3, 3, 4), 99)
    test3 = ('aeiou', 'i')
    test4 = ('aeiou', 'y')
    test5 = ((1, 3, 5 ,6), 4)
    test6 = ((23, 24, 25, 26, 27), 5)
    test7 = ((0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8), 4)
    test8 = ((0, 1, 2,3 ,4 ,5 ,6), 3)
    test9 = ((1, 3), 1)
    test10 = ((2, 10), 10)
    test11 = ((99, 100), 101)
    test12 = ((42,), 42)
    test13= ((43,), 44)
    test14= ((), 99)


    testList = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, test11, test12, test13, test14]

    for i in range(len(testList)):
        #print(testList[i][0])
        #print(testList[i][1])
        print( f((testList[i][0]), testList[i][1]))
```

Comment: You don't pass a string in the first place. Pass a *reference* to the function. `def isMemberR(x,y): ...; bintest(isMemberR)`.

Comment: and specifically for strings you can use `eval`. So `eval(f)(...)`

Answer (score 2):

`'isMemberR'` *is* a string, presumably the *name* of the function you want to pass.

To pass the actual function, you could do

```
bintest(isMemberR)
```